# 'Many To One' attribute type should not be a container

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have this class:

```
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

@Entity
@Table(name="t_user")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Data
public class User implements Serializable, UserDetails {

@Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return null;
    }
..
}
```

but I have this compilation error:

```
'Many To One' attribute type should not be a container
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`@ManyToOne` should annotate a field not a collection. For collection fields the right annotation is `@OneToMany`.

So if you have

```
@ManyToOne
private List<Something> list;
```

that should be

```
@OneToMany
private List<Something> list;
```

Answer (score 4):

As Error says manyToOne should not be collection/list but should be single ojbect

```
@ManyToOne
Somthing somthing; // but not list
```

Answer (score 0):

1- @ManyToOne annotate a field,like that, in Hall classe:

```
@ManyToOne
private Cinema cinema;
```

2- @OneToMany annotate a collection, like that, in Cinema classe:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy ="cinema")
private Collection<Hall> halls;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
private List<Address> address;
```

Since is a One-to-Many relationship, you must that, the other side is a list of something, i.e List something